# Netbeans compiler log

Tags: compiler-construction, netbeans, logging, javac

I have been looking for the compiler logs in netbeans but i can't find them.
The intent is to see which parameters are passed to javac when pressing the clean & build button.
Can anyone help?

Regards

Answer (score 6):

I've just faced same problem and found the solution:

Follow the below steps in NetBeans 7.0:
Open the "Output" window (CTRL+4), at the left bottom of that window you'll find a tool-like icon "Ant's settings", click over it, now on the Ant Options window on "Verbosity level" choose "Verbose" (instead than "Normal"), finally "OK".
Now simply Run->Clean & Build Main Project: on the Output window now you'll read some raws like:
Compilation arguments:

```
'-d'
'D:\Documenti\NetBeansProjects\AppVitM\build\compiled'
'-classpath'
'D:\Documenti\NetBeansProjects\AppVitM\build\compiled'
'-sourcepath'
'D:\Documenti\NetBeansProjects\AppVitM\build\preprocessed'
'-target'
'1.3'
'-bootclasspath'
'C:\S60\devices\S60_3rd_MIDP_SDK_FP1_4\lib\hmidps60v31.jar'
'-encoding'
'UTF-8'
'-g'
'-source'
'1.3'
```

Hope to have been useful, Best Regards, Vittorio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find it here:

```
user-home\.netbeans\6.9\var\log
```

This is for 6.9 version. Adapt it to your version.

Comment: there are some logs there,but i can't see the command that netbeans sends to the javac compiler. i guess netbeans just might not log that kind of info...